# Cannot turn on code folcing in githubu documents in r markdown

Tags: github, r-markdown

Hi all I would like to include a user toggle for code folding in my .Rmd documents.  I am using output: github_document and I found the abilit to do this with  html_documents ([as described here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#code-folding)) but I get an error when I include the command in my github_document like so...

```
---
title: "example"
author: "this guy"
date: "20/01/2021"
output:
  github_document:
    code_folding: hide
---
```

Knitting the document results in an error.

```
Error in (function (toc = FALSE, toc_depth = 3, number_sections = FALSE,  : 
  unused argument (code_folding = "hide")
Calls: <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call
Execution halted
```

Am I missing a package or is it just not available for github_documents in .Rmd files period?

Answer (score 1):

Currently `github_document()` format does not support code folding.